# Windows Phone - Debug info lines cause the program to malfunction

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-phone-8

Hi I'm developing a windows phone app and I use

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()
```

function to write some debug info and when I run the program in debug mode while my phone is connected to my computer and visual studio there is no problem. but when I run the program without debugger - while installed in each of release and debug mode - those lines of debug info cause the app to encounter an exception!

can anybody explain what's going in there?

Comment: What exception do you get? And showing a little bit more code will help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if debugger is attached, then execute codes specific for debugging purpose only if `IsAttached` value is true :

```
if(System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine();
}
```